# Forecasting by Random Forest Regression

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I did forecasting using Random Forest. But the "pred" values after fitting the model are
coming out to be the same. I have tried my best to fix it but couldn't. Please go through my
code and comment.

```
# Reading the file

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Krish Ghosh\Desktop\BSE Sensex.csv', usecols=[1])
df.head() 

# Defining Lags


df['Close Lag1']=df['Close'].shift(+1)
df['Close Lag2']=df['Close'].shift(+2)
df['Close Lag3']=df['Close'].shift(+3)
df

# To drop the NaN values

df=df.dropna()
df

# To concatenate

import numpy as np
X1,X2,X3,Y=df['Close Lag1'],df['Close Lag2'],df['Close Lag3'],df['Close']
X1,X2,X3,Y=np.array(X1),np.array(X2),np.array(X3),np.array(Y)
X1,X2,X3,Y=X1.reshape(-1,1),X2.reshape(-1,1),X3.reshape(-1,1),Y.reshape(-1,1)
X =np.concatenate((X3,X2,X1),axis=1)
print(X)

# To split into Training and Testing 

trainX = X[:-70]
testX = X[-70:]
trainY = Y[:-70]
testY = Y[-70:]

# Random Forest Regressor

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,max_features=3, random_state=1)

# To fit the model and to predict

model.fit(trainX,trainY)
predX = model.predict(testX)

# To print

print(predX)
55697.0029 55697.0029 55639.2479 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029 55697.0029
```

As you can see all the values are same (which is absurd). Please let me know where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After you `fit`, what is `model.score(trainX, trainY)`? If you set `verbose` in `RandomForestRegressor`, anything interesting printed?

Comment: all your testX have the same value?

Comment: Nopes, testX has different values. If u share ur email id then I can share the .ipynb file with u.

Comment: The model.score(trainX, trainY) is coming out to be 0.9988. I set verbose in the Random Forest Regressor but it's the same output I am getting. Not different at all.

Comment: And what is `model.score(testX, testY)`?  If you randomly sample from `X` and `Y` to generate `trainX/testX` and `testX/testY`, do you have similar results?

Comment: model.score(testX,testY) is -4.513. But why would I do it at all? Moreover, since it is related to Time Series Forecasting, so I just can't randomly select trainX, trainY, testX and testY. As you can see from the code, I have selected the last 70 datapoints for my test size. Please let me know what else needs to be done.

Comment: Please share ur email id so that I can send you the .ipynb file alongwith the data.